# In eclipse, how can i see the assembly translation of the java code?

Tags: java, assembly

I mean the intel assembly for the processor?

Comment: As you can see in the answers, it finally seems that the title was not enough. What exactly do you want to see? Did you mean Java bytecode?

Comment: Intel assembly clearly means machine code, not byte code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see the native code generated (at runtime) by the JIT compiler, then there are a series of JVM flags that will print the assembly code as it is generated.

They are included in [this listing](http://www.md.pp.ru/~eu/jdk6options.html) - search for `"PrintAssembly"`.

Note that these options need to be prefixed with `"-XX:"` in the `java` command line.  Refer to the `java` manual page for details.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get anything like that. Java is compiled to ByteCode.

Comment: My guess is this is what is required ;)

Answer (score 0):

Java-code is translated to [bytecode](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Java_bytecode). Then the JVM takes the bytecode and executes it. So I think you are out of luck.

If you want the bytecode - see [javap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html). It ships with the JDK and disassembles a class  file. As @arjan noted, Eclipse shows such information when you double-click a class.

Comment: Perhaps he meant to say, "how to see the compiled byte code"?  But only the OP knows for sure. We await his response. :)

Comment: bytecode is 'usually' decompilable to java easily and reading byte code aint any harder

Comment: ah, there was a tool for getting the byte-code of a class. let me find it.

Comment: Why using separate tools? The OP mentioned he's using Eclipse, and Eclipse shows the byte code by default simply by double clicking on a class file.

Comment: @arjan - correct. Mine doesn't, because I use a decompiler always :) but yes

Comment: @Bozho  
posted one, already; another is asm, bcel; both(!!) are used in sun jdk internally

Answer (score -1):

http://java.decompiler.free.fr/

but I guess that's extra easy to be found oneself.

Comment: Not sure what that is supposed to be. That link is dead.

Answer (score -1):

If with "assembly translation" you mean the byte code (the output from Javac, JDT, etc) then the answer is really simple: find a .class file and double click on it.

This will show you the byte code in human readable mnemonics.

Answer (score -2):

Enter the output folder - usually "bin" - in the Navigation perspective.  There you can see all your class files.